# error: reference to non-static member function must be called when using std::thread with function that takes in a pointer

Tags: c++, multithreading, sdl-2

I'm just trying to do some multi threading in my program and one of my functions is called `Setup` which is called like this: `Setup(renderer);` and declared as `void Setup(SDL_Renderer *renderer);` but when I try and make a thread run the function I get an error: `error: reference to non-static member function must be called` at the line: `std::thread th1(Setup, renderer);`. How can I make another thread run that function of the program?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Setup is a member function. If so, a simple way to invoke it is with a lambda passed to `std::thread`:

```
std::thread th1([this, renderer](){ this->Setup(renderer); });
```

When invoking a member function, the compiler is going to need to know which object to invoke the function on. If you just do `std::thread(Setup, renderer)`, the compiler has no way of knowing what object instance to invoke the Setup function on.

You need to pass that instance to the thread somehow - using a lambda as I showed is one way to do that. `this` is only valid if you are trying to construct the thread within a member function of the object with the Setup function. If not, here is a slightly different example:

```
// You have some class with a Setup function...
class A { public: void Setup(SDL_Renderer* renderer); };

// You have an instance of that class:
A a_instance;

// You have the argument to the function
SDL_Renderer* renderer = /**/;

// You want to create a thread that runs A::setup on a_instance
std::thread th1([a = &a_instance, renderer]()
{
    a->Setup(renderer);
});
```

Comment: Ok, a few things with that. What is ```this``` in the example, is it the name of the class? The class, and declaration of the function ```Setup``` isn't static, im not sure if that information is helpful. Other thing is it gives me another weird error: ```undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5' ```

Comment: When you are inside of a non-static member function (a function in a class), `this` always refers to the object on which the function is being invoked. The thread is being created inside of some function being called on some instance of an object - `this` is that instance. We pass `this` into the lambda so that the thread can invoke the `Setup` function on the appropriate object.

For the undefined reference - you probably need to link to pthread.

Comment: Will that work properly if im also doing the multithreading inside a function that belongs to the same class?

Comment: Ok, it compiled but now my code displays a black rectangle instead of some text?

Comment: Sounds like a different issue you will have to work out. Yes is will or can work if the multithreading is inside a function belonging to the same class.

Comment: On your edit, will that work if im using multithreading within the declaration of a class? As in ```test.cpp``` and ```test.h``` but i make an instance elsewhere in another file?

Comment: You can create the thread inside the class or elsewhere - either one will work. All you need to ensure is that the correct instance is passed into the lambda function. That instance could be `this` when inside a member function or another instance of the class retrieved from anywhere else. It does not matter where the instance is made.

Comment: would there be any reason that without multithreading, drawing some text works file, but then using another thread, it draws a black rectangle but still has the functionality of like highlight copy paste?